# extract the last updated timestamp from outlook item

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to find out the last recieved email in each outlook folder. for some reason, i can print it but cannot assign it to variable.

the set dat =obj.LastModificationTime is throwing exception. how can i fix it?

```
   Private Sub ProcessFolder(folder As MAPIFolder)

Dim folder2 As MAPIFolder
Dim obj As Object
Dim size As Double

Dim dat As Object
Set dat = Empty
If Not folder.Items Is Nothing Then
    For Each obj In folder.Items

        size = size + obj.size
        If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
       Debug.Print obj.LastModificationTime
      Set dat = obj.LastModificationTime
       End If


    Next
End If
 ' Create The Object
'Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' How To Write To A File


Debug.Print Now() & "," & folder.Name & "," & folder.Items.Count & "," & size & "," & folder.FolderPath & "," & dat
Set dat = Empty


'File.Write folder.Name & "," & folder.Items.Count & "," & size & "," & folder.FolderPath

For Each folder2 In folder.Folders
    ProcessFolder folder2
Next
'File.Close
End Sub

Sub FolderSize()

    'Needs reference to MS Outlook Object Library

   'Needs reference to MS Outlook Object Library

    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim InboxMsg As Object
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.folder
    Dim SystemEmails As String

     Dim filter As String
       Dim olParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olFolderA As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olFolderB As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") '

    Set olParentFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    For Each olFolderA In olParentFolder.Folders
       ' Debug.Print olFolderA.FolderPath, olFolderA.Items.Count, olFolderA.Folders.Count

        ProcessFolder olFolderA

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Declare dat as String, Date or Variant then remove Set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all items in the folder:

```
If Not folder.Items Is Nothing Then
    For Each obj In folder.Items
```

Instead, you can use the `Sort` method of the `Items` class which sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method.

```
Sub SortByDueDate() 
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim myItem As Object
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items 

 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items 
 myItems.Sort "[LastModificationTime]", False 

 For Each myItem In myItems 
   Debug.Print myItem.Subject & "-- " & myItem.DueDate 
 Next myItem

End Sub
```

And you don't need to use the `Set` keyword to assign a date time structure. `Set` is used to assign a reference to an object.

```
dat = obj.LastModificationTime
```

Answer (score 0):

`LastModificationTime` is a scalar property (`DateTime` in this case), not an object. "`Set`" is only required in VB/VBA/VBS for the objects.